# how to list object in aws s3 using S3QL

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-s3, command-line, mount, s3ql

I'm following this tutorial [http://ubuntuservergui.com/ubuntu-server-guide/mount-s3-ubuntu-server] to mount my s3 bucket, setup already done, but i don't know how to list object and anything else.

in command line I do cd /mnt/s3

and i'm only found lost+found file

anyone can help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

S3QL doesn't allow you to browse existing S3 objects. You can only read what you've previously stored using S3QL (and the object names will not correspond to the file names).